# Python Twitter JSON cannot extract location, place nor time_zone

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have to do an analysis of streamed twitter data.

```
tweets_data_path = 'allnews.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
except:
    continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()
```

I am trying to run the following 2 lines:

```
tweets['Location'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)
tweets['time_zone'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['time_zone'] if 'time_zone' in tweet else ' ', tweets_data)
```

For the first line I get:

```
KeyError: 'place'
```

Which is strange because place does exist although it is sometimes null

For the second line I get no error, but the column is just empty although time zones do exist in the JSON.

Here are extracts from the JSON:

```
"place":null(note that there aren't quotations around null)

"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)"

"location":"London"
```

What I have noticed is that sometimes place is null but then there is a location.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm starting to become desperate! :')

**EDIT**

Also, when I only use 1/4 of the JSON the "place" error doesn't appear

Comment: Having a blanket except is usually not a good idea,  have you iterated over the list to verify the keys exist?

Comment: Hi, yes I did. Here is the output:  [u'contributors', u'truncated', u'text', u'in_reply_to_status_id', u'id', u'favorite_count', u'source', u'retweeted', u'coordinates', u'timestamp_ms', u'entities', u'in_reply_to_screen_name', u'id_str', u'retweet_count', u'in_reply_to_user_id', u'favorited', u'retweeted_status', u'user', u'geo', u'in_reply_to_user_id_str', u'possibly_sensitive', u'lang', u'created_at', u'filter_level', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str', **bold**u'place'**bold**, u'extended_entities']

Comment: shouldn't that list be a list of dicts?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I understand. How do I do this?

Comment: I meant `tweets_data`, you are getting a KeyError because somewhere the key does not exist, add a link to your file content if possible

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was uploading the file: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/tktzpjqm4y93sgo/news11pm.txt?dl=0]

Comment: Ok you have three dicts that look like `{u'limit': {u'track': 5, u'timestamp_ms': u'1441402926876'}}` indexes 5817,5839,5826

Comment: Because I don't quite understand the problem could you please help me to solve it? And thank you.

Comment: time_zone is hardly in there at all if indeed at all, what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: I would like to make a frequency table with the locations and with the time zones for plotting in bar plots. (I do know that the locations do not represent the sample well though).

Comment: The problem is `"time_zone"` does not appear anywhere in the json keys, it is in a nested dicts, also even catching where the three dicts where place does not exist i get very little data in the column that is not None so you have very little output

Comment: I think I understand. I'm having the same problem with retweets using the line `tweets['retweet_count'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['retweet_count'] if 'retweet_count' in tweet else ' ', tweets_data)
` this just returns a column full of 0's. Is it the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many issues in your code, the biggest being time_zone not being a key in your json, it appears in some json but in a nested dict. This will create the df:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('news11pm.txt')as f:

    tweets_data = []
    for line in f:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            pass


tweets = pd.DataFrame()
import numpy as np
tweets['Location'] = [tweet['place']['country']if "place" in tweet and tweet['place'] else np.nan for tweet in tweets_data ]
tweets['time_zone'] = [tweet['time_zone'] if 'time_zone' in tweet else np.nan for tweet in tweets_data]
```

Calling dropna on the df gives us an empty df! That is because `time_zone` does not exist as a key so all the `time_zone` column is full of nans:

```
print(tweets["Location"].dropna())

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Location, time_zone]
Index: []
```

To debug the problem a few simple steps will help piece it together:

```
# find if there are missing keys and  where
for ind, d in enumerate(tweets_data):
    if "time_zone" not in d:
        print("No time_zone {}".format(ind))
    elif "place" not in d:
        print("No place {}".format(ind))
```

That loop confirms that `time_zone` does in fact not exist as  a key and `place` is missing in two dicts so to find where `time_zone` is we look for a dict in the values of each dict and find what is the key that will get us that dict.

```
# now we know time_zone does not exist as a key, 
# check if it is in a nested dict value
for ind, d in enumerate(tweets_data):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict) and "time_zone" in v:
            print(k, ind, v["time_zone"])
```

So after debugging we find that time_zone exists in a nested dict with the key `user` so putting that together:

```
import numpy as np

tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['Location'] = [tweet['place']['country'] if "place" in tweet and tweet['place']
                      else np.nan for tweet in tweets_data]
tweets['time_zone'] = [tweet["user"]['time_zone'] if "user" in tweet and tweet["user"]['time_zone']
                       else np.nan for tweet in tweets_data]
```

Now calling drop_na we get something a little more useable:

```
                 Location                    time_zone
17         United Kingdom                       London
269         United States   Eastern Time (US & Canada)
378                México  Mountain Time (US & Canada)
409                 India                      Chennai
660        United Kingdom                Europe/London
1010               France                         Rome
1125               Polska                       Warsaw
1689        United States   Eastern Time (US & Canada)
1902        United States   Central Time (US & Canada)
1929                Kenya                      Baghdad
2248       United Kingdom                       London
2300       United Kingdom                       London
2441       United Kingdom                       Hawaii
2491               España                       Hawaii
2500       United Kingdom                    Amsterdam
2534        United States   Pacific Time (US & Canada)
....................................
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. One more question. Although all the other variables extract without issues, why does "retweet_count" return a column full of 0's. I can see in the .txt that it exceeds 0's rather often?

Comment: @ishido, I added how to get the time_zone, if you use the same logic as I have with the loops in the code, you will be able to find what you need.

Comment: Yes after working through your explanation I've understood! Thank you for this extremely useful and thorough answer!

Comment: No worries, the `'retweeted_status'` is where you find the interesting `'retweet_count'`, it is just a matter of studying some of the json and figuring out where the relevant data lies, that I will leave to yourself ;)